# Android: How do I create a Fragment that extends from AppCompatPreference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-preferences

I'm trying to create an app with a navigation bar. The navigation bar will have options to go to, such as the `SettingsActivity` which will have preferences.

For navigation bars, I know you're meant to switch between fragments in a `MainActivity` to switch between as the user clicks on the different fragments.

However, I need different fragments within my Settings page so I think that I need to use an activity (i.e `SettingsActivity`) for each of the different headers. My settings activity needs to extend from `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`but if it were a fragment, I would have to extend it from `Fragment` as well.

But because Android Studio does not support Nested Fragments I don't know what I should do.

Thank you

Comment: You can nest Fragments in Android. You just can't do it in XML.

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, it doesn't "not" support nested fragments either. In fact, the two things are orthogonal. Anyways, this might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html along with https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2#NestedFragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a SettingsActivity via android studio you will notice that it is using some fragments that extend `PreferenceFragment`. This class is deprecated thus you should use (as it is stated in the documentation) the class `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`

You can create a Fragment that extends `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat` and show it manually.

Or You can create a fragment and show a list of desired settings and show the fragments you created using the method `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: Instead of the android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat, you can just extend it from PreferenceFragmentCompat which was what I found worked for me and import that class. But other than that, it works. Thank you